# Overwriting core block using plugin method

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have created a module in which i am overwriting core functionality of product listing widget. I can achieve this using preference but i want to understand plugin method..
Below is my code for frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList">
        <plugin name="widget_product_listing_add_attribute" type="Test\CatalogWidget\Plugin\Block\Product\ProductsListAddAttributePlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

and below is my code for plugin block.

```
namespace Test\CatalogWidget\Plugin\Block\Product;

class ProductsListAddAttributePlugin
{
    public function beforeCreateCollection(\Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList $subject, \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $result)
    {
        /**
        * @var \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList $subject
        * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $result
        */

        die('ProductsListAddAttributePlugin before....');
        
    }
}
```

after installing module and running di:compile.. when i reload the page i am getting below error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
> function
> Test\CatalogWidget\Plugin\Block\Product\ProductsListAddAttributePlugin::beforeCreateCollection(),
> 1 passed in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\hello\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php
> on line 121 and exactly 2 expected in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\hello\app\code\Test\CatalogWidget\Plugin\Block\Product\ProductsListAddAttributePlugin.php:6
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\hello\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(121):
> Test\CatalogWidget\Plugin\Block\Product\ProductsListAddAttributePlugin->beforeCreateCollection(Object(Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList\Interceptor))
>
> ## 1 C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\hello\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153):
>
> Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
>
> ## 2 C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\hello\generated\code\Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList\Interceptor.php(26):
>
> Mag in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\hello\app\code\Test\CatalogWidget\Plugin\Block\Product\ProductsListAddAttributePlugin.php
> on line 6

Comment: Please refer to : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: I did but still i am getting above error, can you help me out that where i am doing things wrong..@RakeshJakhar

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `setup:di:compile` and clear the cache? after updating the `beforeCreateCollection` method?

It looks like you're correctly passing two arguments through, but it might be referring to an older DI.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the generated code 
I think you working under Windows you can run the following command on your prompt terminal. 
Make sure first that you are under developer mode

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

php rm -rf generated*
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```